# Use one Class of an Object with Multiple

Tags: r

This is a general question motivated by a specific event.

When an object holds multiple classes, each with different generic actions, how can I specify to use "this" class, rather than "that" class?

The example code here is bundled with geepack.

```
library(stargazer)
library(geepack)

data(dietox)
dietox$Cu <- as.factor(dietox$Cu)
mf <- formula(Weight~Cu*(Time+I(Time^2)+I(Time^3)))

gee0 <- glm(mf, data = dietox, family = poisson("identity")) # a wrong model
gee1 <- geeglm(mf, data=dietox, id=Pig, family=poisson("identity"),corstr="ar1")

class(gee0)
class(gee1)

summary(gee0)
summary(gee1)

stargazer(gee0, type = "text")
stargazer(gee1, type = "text")
```

I'd like to work with the "glm" class object, not the "geeglm" class object.

@Richard Scriven: I'd just like to pull the results out into a stargazer(...) report. Thanks for the clarifying question.

Comment: What specific action are you trying to perform using the  `glm` class?

Comment: You can do `class(gee1) <- "glm"` .

Comment: The [stargazer pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf) says that both `gee` and `glm` are supported so there are probably methods for both, I presume (never used that package though).

Comment: I thought so too! But it's bonking on me. I'll take the question to Marek at stargazer, because I think this seems to be more of a specific problem rather than a general question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class system that uses the `class(foo)` attribute is not strongly typed.  The class vector is used by R to determine  which methods to use when that object is passed to a generic like `print`.  For example, if you were to call `print(gee1)`, R would first search for a function called `print.geeglm` which, in this case, it would find in the package geepack, and R calls that function with the arguments supplied to `print()`.

If R did not find a function called `print.geeglm`, it would then search for `print.gee`, then `print.glm`, then `print.default`.

So in short, `gee1` does not contain 3 objects with different classes, it is a single object with a class vector that informs R where to look for generic methods.

To make things slightly more confusing R has multiple type systems and the class vetcor is used by the S3 type system.  A google search for "R s3 class" will get you lots more info on R's class system.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the oversight.  Corrected the first sentence accordingly.

Comment: Thanks to both @Jthorpe and @agstudy. Cleared up that in this instance it isn't holding `foo` as a class per se, but giving a search path for operations.

Comment: It's good knowledge, but I don't really see how this answers the question.  It's just general knowledge about method dispatching